# Error setting rewrite jetty 9.4.8

Tags: url-rewriting, jetty

I'm trying to set url rewrite in jetty 9.4.8.

I am using configuration file below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler"> 
  <Set name="handler">
    <New id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
      <Set name="handler">
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
        <Set name="contextPath">/QuestionWeb</Set>
        <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.base"/>\QuestionWeb.war</Set>
          <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>
          <Set name="copyWebDir">true</Set>
        </New>
      </Set>
      <Set name="rewriteRequestURI">true</Set>
      <Set name="rewritePathInfo">false</Set>
      <Set name="originalPathAttribute">requestedPath</Set>      
      <Call name="addRule">
        <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewritePatternRule">
          <Set name="pattern">/test</Set>
            <Set name="replacement">/question</Set>
          </New>
        </Arg>
      </Call>
     </New>
  </Set>  
</Configure>
```

After starting the java -jar server start.jar, redirection only works first to access the address:

http://localhost:8080/QuestionWeb/queston

Then access the address:

http://localhost:8080/QuestionWeb/test

If I try to access address "http://localhost:8080/QuestionWeb/test" before that address "http://localhost:8080/QuestionWeb/queston" I get error status 404.

My Servelt Code:

```java
@WebServlet("/question")
public class QuestonServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS");
    public QuestonServlet() { }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append(df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())).append(request.getContextPath());
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a very complicated setup (with many red flags).  How are you starting Jetty?